# Jquery datatable click event is not firing for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery Click event is firing for first time but on second time it is not triggering.

**Datatable:**

```
var tableAttendance = $('#tableAttendance').dataTable ({
        "bDestroy"       : true,
        "bAutoWidth"     : false,
        "bServerSide"    : true,
        "bDeferRender"   : true,
        "sServerMethod"  : "POST",
        "sAjaxSource"    : pageUrl (),
        "sAjaxDataProp"  : "aaData",
        "aaSorting"      : [[2, 'desc']],
        "fnCreatedRow": function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            $(nRow).attr({
                "data-toggle":"context",
                "data-target":"#attendance-context-menu"
            });
        },
        "aoColumns"      : [
        {
            "mData" : function (row, type, set) {
                return '<div>'+ row['Employee_Name'] +'</div>';
            }
        }]
    });
```

Jquery Event                         :

```
    $(document).on('click contextmenu', '#tableAttendance tbody tr', function (e) {
    console.log("Event Triggered");
    var selectRow = $(this);

     if (!selectRow.hasClass('row_selected'))
     {
          selectRow.addClass('row_selected');
     }
     else
     {
          //Other than right click. Because i use multi-select option
          if( e.button !== 2 ) 
             selectRow.removeClass('row_selected');
     }
   });
```

Working for different row select event. But when i right click(context menu) same row more than once, the event is not triggring

Comment: Where does the variable `e` get defined? Adding row_selected works, but removing does not, because `e` is undefined for me.

Comment: Is their any scenario in which event is not firing second time onwards?

Comment: Have a look at my edit. The check for e.button on right-click is always giving false

Answer (score 0):

Just tested and your code works for me.

Could you please try to modify your click handler as follows:

```
$(document).on('click contextmenu', '#dummy tbody tr', function () {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log("Event Triggered" + d.getMilliseconds());
});
```

If you are debugging with firebug it could well be that you overlooked the number in front of your logged text.

[image]

Messages with the exact same content logged multiple times result in the number being incremented.

Adding milliseconds to the output will slightly modify the message and result in a new line of output.

EDIT:

A right click will result in the value `e.button = 2`.

This value is checked in your handler `if( e.button !== 2 )` and does not execute `selectRow.removeClass('row_selected');` because the result of the check is `false`.

Completely removing the check for `e.button` would get your right-click to select and deselect the rows.

Comment: Click event is working fine. But right click context menu event is not triggering for second time